# How to download all listed files from a webpage where the URL’s do not have filenames defined

Tags: curl, web-scraping, wget

I would like to download all the datasets from this page: http://www.data.gov/catalog/geodata/category/0/agency/0/filter/sort/page/1/count/20

I have tried wget, but here is the challenge:

There is no filename in the URL’s linking to the file and they may have different file types.

Here is an example of an URL to a file: http://www.data.gov/download/CECA1FB2-EA36-537B-8C68-298CCA449697/geodata

The pattern is that all URL’s start with http:// www.data.gov/download/ and ends with /geodata

What is the best way to do scrape this website? Should I use wget, cURL, a PHP script or something else?

Comment: I am still wondering about this so any comment or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why won't wget work in this case? Based on your example URLs, a recursive wget retrieval will put each downloaded file into a file "geodata" in its own directory. Once it's on your local disk, you can do with the data how you'd like, including renaming and moving the files into a more convenient form (e.g. using mmv or a find -exec command).